# Rails refactoring link_to if params present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Rails 5.1 and have this code snippet.
How can I refactor it to make it more readable?

In views/imagecapturings/index.html.erb

```
<% if params.has_key?(:select) %>
<%= link_to 'St. Gallen', digitized_in_stgallen_imagecapturings_path('select[year]' => params[:select][:year], 'select[month]' => params[:select][:month]) %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to 'St. Gallen', action: "digitized_in_stgallen", method: :get %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would say it is ok as it is

Comment: I have 5 more links like this one on the same page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ternary operator

```
<%= params.has_key?(:select) ?
    link_to('St. Gallen', digitized_in_stgallen_imagecapturings_path('select[year]' => params[:select][:year], 'select[month]' => params[:select][:month])) :    
    link_to('St. Gallen', action: "digitized_in_stgallen", method: :get) %>
```